# Bacula stops writing to disk volume after 2GB

Tags: bacula

Bacula Version: 5.2.5

I have configured bacula to write volumes to disk, however bacula stops writing to the volume as soon as it reaches 2gb. The file system is not an issue as I have stored files larger than 2gb.

```
06-Dec 17:22 backup-sd JobId 8421: End of Volume "Full-Monthly-0005" at 0:2147475577 on device "FileStorage" (/nfs/backup-pool). Write of 64512 bytes got 8069.
06-Dec 17:22 backup-sd JobId 8421: End of medium on Volume "Full-Monthly-0005" Bytes=2,147,475,578 Blocks=33,288 at 06-Dec-2012 17:22.


backup1@backup:/nfs/backup-pool$ ls -alh Full-Monthly-0005 <br>
-rw-r----- 1 bacula tape 2.0G Dec  3 16:14 Full-Monthly-0005

bacula-dir.conf:
Pool {
 Name = Full-Monthly
 Pool Type = Backup
 Recycle = yes
 Volume Retention = 5 months
 Volume Use Duration = 1 day
 Maximum Volumes = 5
 Maximum Volume Bytes = 12gb
}

bacula-sd.conf:
Device {
 Name = FileStorage
 Media Type = File
 Archive Device = /nfs/backup-pool
 LabelMedia = yes                   # lets Bacula label unlabeled media
 Random Access = Yes
 RemovableMedia = no
 AlwaysOpen = no
 Label media = yes
 Maximum Volume Size = 12gb
}
```

In my original configuration Maximum Volume Bytes and Maximum Volume Size were not set at all and so should have defauted to no maximum but that did not work either.

Answer (score 1):

> The file system is not an issue as I have stored files larger than 2gb

Check again. The filesystem is apparently mounted over NFS and NFSv2 clients can only get to the first 2GB of a file. Thus, even if the filesystem has other 2GB+ files on it, they can't be fully handled over NFS.

Comment: Asker (apparently) commented (via an attempted suggested edit) that editing `etc/autofs.master` from
`backup-pool -nfsvers=2 server:/path` to
`backup-pool -fstype=nfs4 server:/path` worked. See http://serverfault.com/review/suggested-edits/43385